# Recaptcha issue in China

Tags: recaptcha

We have an issue related to the Recaptcha, it is not working in China as google is blocked.

As per the below link, 
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/recaptcha/XBhetkVgh84

We need to replace the 'www.google.com' with 'www.recaptcha.net'.

But we also have the following url given in the app.config file.

```
<add key="GRecaptcha" value="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"/>
```

So, could you please let me know replacing the www.google.com in the app.config with 'www.recaptcha.net' will fix this issue? Do I need to change anything in angular-recaptcha.js file also?

Also, could you please let me know if there is any other solution to fix this issue in China?

Comment: The app config setting is <add key="GRecaptcha" value="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"/>

Answer (score 3):

from my experince changing url to recaptcha.net doesnt work.
This is because the url recaptcha.net/api.js download a second javascript file by an xhr request, and this script contains google domain urls. 
As this script generate a google iframe for generating the captcha, you cannot even modify this in jquery for example

Answer (score 0):

NetEase a.k.a 163 provides similar service:

https://www.163yun.com/product/captcha

The page is in Chinese so you might need google translate if you do not speak the language.